# Generic Image type emgu C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am using Emgu OpenCV wrapper and I need to support different types of images. However, I am trying to avoid declaring different image for each supported image type ( e.g. do the following)

```
    private Image<Gray, Byte> m_GrayImage8;
    private Image<Gray, UInt16> m_GrayImage16;
    private Image<Gray, UInt32> m_GrayImage32;

    private Image<Bgr, Byte> m_BgrImage8;
    private Image<Bgr, UInt16> m_BgrImage16;

    private Image<Bgra, Byte> m_BgraImage8;
    private Image<Bgra, UInt16> m_BgraImage16;

    private Image<Hsv, Byte> m_HsvImage8;
    private Image<Hsv, UInt16> m_HsvImage16;

    private Image<Hls, Byte> m_HlsImage8;
    private Image<Hls, UInt16> m_HlsImage16;

    private Image<Lab, Byte> m_LabImage8;
    private Image<Lab, UInt16> m_LabImage16;

    private Image<Luv, Byte> m_LuvImage8;
    private Image<Luv, UInt16> m_LuvImage16;

    private Image<Xyz, Byte> m_XyzImage8;
    private Image<Xyz, UInt16> m_XyzImage16;

    private Image<Ycc, Byte> m_YccImage8;
    private Image<Ycc, UInt16> m_YccImage16;
```

Initially, doing the above was the easy way of implementing different types of images. However, I am looking for better approach. So, I tried doing the following

```
Image<IColor, Byte> m_GrayImage8;
```

However, I still need to do one for each pixel size.   Is there a way to get

```
Image<IColor, T> m_GrayImage8;
```

where T some interface that can be casted to different types.???  any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a generic image you can create a method like this one:

```
public static void GenericImageMethod<TColor, TDepth>(Image<TColor, TDepth> frame)
                  where TColor : struct, IColor
                  where TDepth : new() 
{
        Image<TColor, TDepth> image_output = frame.Copy();
        //Modify the image_output as you need...
        return image_output;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to declare a generic image type as a member of a class?